# I want to show image over text. Suppose when i am putting cursor over text then need to show image

Tags: javascript, css

I wanted to show image when putting cursor over text in question text. Please give me idea

Comment: show what have you tried. Provide some of your code

Comment: Have you heard of [ToolTip](https://popper.js.org/tooltip-examples.html)?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to achieve this.

1. use tooltips. Following link contains usage and explanation of tooltips.
   https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_tooltip.asp
2. using css. simply take an img tag inside a div and toggle display on hover of that text.

**HTML:**

```
<p>lorem ipsum .... <img src="source.jpg"></p>
```

**CSS:**

```
p img{
 display: none;
}

p:hover img{
 display: block;
}
```